# JS file not loading

Tags: javascript, html

My ebrithil.js file is simply not loading. Can anyone explain why?
http://www.rainbowdoge.esy.es

Comment: Did you try to google it before posting this question? I'm sure you're not the first one it happens to him.

Comment: In source code I can't find definition. Are you sure that you did include it?

Comment: It's like the third line from the bottom.

Comment: I don't see any reason for it not to load right off the bat. Could you try adding `alert("Hello world");` to the top of the file and uploading it? That way you can easily verify if it is or is not loading.

Comment: `<iframe>` must be closed by an `</iframe>` ending tag. Omitting it will make all the remaining of your markup as descendant of your iframe, thus getting ignored since this iframe has an src attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `<iframe>` tag.

```
<iframe src="player.html" id="videoIframe" name="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

> "[...]both the starting and ending tag are mandatory."- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

remove this one some think wrong this fram

```
<iframe src="player.html" id="videoIframe" name="" allowfullscreen>
```

and than js working fine ?

Answer (score -1):

try putting using this line

> link rel="stylesheet" **type="text/css"** href="ebrithil.css"

This should resolve it for you.

Comment: I saw the answer, please learn html and then demote my answer. You can see that he's missing the type in his css inclusion. Good day.